# Problems with the salt and md5 encryption when login

Tags: php, html, md5, salt

I have managed to create a basic encryption system so when a user initially signs up to my website the password is stored in my database safely using salt, md5 and sha1.

The problem occurs now when the user is logging in, the string (password) that is sent to the database is different even though I am using the same method. I shall demonstrate below:

This is my basic (for now) add customer to database page using the salt technique.

```
require "dbconn.php";

$username = $_GET['username'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$pass = $_GET['pwd1'];
$pass2 =$_GET['pwd2'];
$matching = 0;

if($pass == $pass2)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.alert('Your details have been successfully          registered, please proceed to login with your new credentials!')</script>";
echo '<script>javascript:window.close();</script>';

$salt = sha1(md5($pass));
$pass = md5($pass.$salt);

$query = "INSERT INTO customer VALUES    ('".$username."','".$email."','".$pass."','face1.jpg')";
```

Again this is my basic (for now) login page again using the same salt technique (i have left out the latter part of this page)

```
session_start();
require "dbconn.php";

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$salt = sha1(md5($password));
$password = md5($password.$salt);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username ='".$username."' AND   password='".$password."'";
```

I have done some checks and when putting a password into the database
eg using the password name test: it is stored as 34364c859afb02e70306c905374ac2 but when a user logs in the password is: 34364c859afb02e70306c905374ac2d5

Comment: Always escape user input! Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape it, otherwise anyone can exploit your website!

Comment: Look at [this page](http://gnorman.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=238&Itemid=274). Maybe you should change datatype to tinyblob.

Comment: Check the length of the field in database

Comment: Use the `crypt()` function for hashing passwords (or some other recognized hashing library). Unless you are an expert in cryptography you should never, ever, create hashing mechanisms yourself.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen he is using md5 and sha1...

Comment: What you have is not a properly implemented salt, it's just a somewhat custom but not very secure hashing algorithm. The salt must not be derived from the hashed valued itself, otherwise it's pretty pointless.

Comment: Moreover, you're not really using a salted approach. All you're doing really is `$password = md5($password.sha1(md5($password)))`.

Comment: 1. md5/sha1 are not encryption (it's hashing). 2. Even with salt, md5 is considered completely insecure. sha1 is a bit better, but also not great. You should use bcrypt instead - see the `crypt` function, or just use a decent password lib, such as [this one](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) or [this one](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib).

Comment: Thanks alot for your advice guys I see the errors in my ways, this was my first attempt from reading several articles. I will go back and amend it.  Thanks everybody for your time and keep up the hard work. Kind regards

Comment: Use http://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat and be done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a ton of things wrong here:

1. Do NOT transmit passwords in the URL string(GET paramters) because that makes it visible and can leak the password through referrer URLs.
2. Use prepared statements. Do not use the old mysql_* functions. Instead use MySQLi or PDO. Any parameter you send into the database should be through a prepared statement with one of the two with the parameters injected AFTER the statement is prepared. This allows you to use the MySQL driver to escape your parameters and protect you from SQL injection.
3. Stylistically you should use consistent names for your variables.
4. Check your column length. It's probably too short. (2 characters missing)
5. Your salting method doesn't really qualify as a salting method either as it's derived from the original password string. Look into generating a unique salt per user.

Comment: Thanks for your time and giving me some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here:

1. You should not build SQL query using raw user input, you should escape it. I would recommend you to use PDO with prepared statements.
2. Your way to hash/encrypt/store passwords is not secure at all. Try some PHP library that can handle this, it's safer.
3. In your case the problem seems to be the database field length. As you can see the two hashes you provided are almost the same, except the first one 2 char shorter. You should expand your db password field length.

Comment: Thanks for your time and giving me some pointers. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The hash you're storing is too short for a MD5 hash - it's 30 characters long.

You're most likely trimming it. Check the length of your field, it should accommodate 32 characters for the hash.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 characters missing off your string.

```
34364c859afb02e70306c905374ac2
34364c859afb02e70306c905374ac2d5
```

Check your mysql field length.